# Powerful driver circuit for small power stepper motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, driver

i want to drive a small stepper motor, let's say nema 17 ( which is usually below 10 W ) with a big driver circuit that can run motors above 20 W.Can i use that driver and maintaining for a long period ( let's say 2-3 h ) underload ? My logic tells me that it should not be used for large stepper motor, that that driver couldnt deliver such a current and for small power it's ok, but anyway i want to be sure,

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. Compare it to a big guy pushing a small wheel barrow :-)

Comment: The big sumo wrestler may have trouble with a toddlers wheelbarrow, he might just be too big to reach down to the handles.  In the same way the current limiting of a very much too large driver with too high a voltage may cause more power to be dissipated than a small motor can handle if the current limit cannot be set low enough.  The answer is more case dependant and there is not enough information to be sure.